# Generators of the colored braid group (two colors), reference

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, braid-groups

I consider the group $B_{n,n}$, the braids, colored in two colors, say all odd strings are black and all even strings are white.
It is easy to find a set of generators for $B_{n,n}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\def\s{\sigma}
 a)&M_i=\s_{2i-1} \s_{2i}\s_{2i-1} = \s_{2i}\s_{2i-1}\s_{2i}, i=1,\dots,n-1 \\
 b)&N_i=\s_{2i}\s_{2i+1} \s_{2i} = \s_{2i+1} \s_{2i} \s_{2i+1}, i=1,\dots,n-1\\
 c)&P_i=\s_{2i}^2, i=1,\dots,n-1 \\
 d)&Q_i=\s_{2i-1}^2, i=1,\dots,n \\
\end{cases}
$$
and relations $(M_iP_i^{-1}N_i)Q_i(M_iP_i^{-1}N_i)^{-1} = Q_{i+1},
(N_iQ_{i+1}^{-1}M_{i+1})P_i(N_iQ_{i+1}^{-1}M_{i+1})^{-1} = P_{i+1}
$

But I can not find any source where it is proven. Could you give me a reference (paper, textbook)?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108648/relations-in-a-particular-subgroup-of-the-braid-group/108650#108650

Answer (score 3):

А. А. Марков, Основы алгебраической теории кос, Тр. Матем. ин-та им. В. А. Стеклова, 1945, том 16,  страницы 3–53 (Mi tm911), [a link is available here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tm&paperid=911&option_lang=rus)

Comment: I found there nothing about $B_{n,n}$. Which page did you refer to? As far as I see, the article concerns the group $R_n$ which is the groop of pure braids($n$ colours), not coloured in two colors.